# how to put test file in the same directory of the corresponding java file

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, directory, file-structure

right now, at least in Intellij IDE, that, test are always in a seperated folder. Can we change that and instead, add test folder in each corresponding java file directory to contain test files or in the same level of the java file that test file is testing on. Just like what we can do with javascript folder structure.

I heard it was not possible and can't find a solution with googling. Is it true? What's the alternative?

Comment: Out of interest: Why would you want to do that? And how would you seperate your testcode from productioncode when building a jar file? Usually it's better to have the testcode in the same package as the productioncode but in another directory structure ... like `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` if you're using maven i.e.

Comment: @tom well, see, I am mostly working on front end, occationally jump in the backend... javascript have webpack instruct itself what to bundle and ignore file extension like `.test.js` so I suppose since java is soooo senior in term of years in the field, should be not so hard to do the same... no?

Comment: Hmm ok, I'm sure there's some nifty way to do that with java too (depending on your build tool) but imho there just seems to be no good reason to do it, given the de-facto standard tools you get (like maven, gradle et.c) ...

Comment: its just really a pain in term of file navigation, the whole test tree directory break down seems, at least from a js developer perspective, more of a over categorization, that may not really help in term of writing test frequently against writing code at the same time.... just my .1 cent